# Site URL alias using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I am developing a website, however I am trying not to have the unattractive url being displaced example instead of : `/my_project/master_page.php?page=home` and would like to display `/my_project/project/welcome` and so on, I am trying to achieve this by using `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` in the site's root directory.
The code is as follows below:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^project/([^/\.]+)/?$ master_page.php?page=$1 [L]
```

However I must add I do need some major assistance in achieving this, Thank You.

Comment: Keep above rule in `my_project/.htaccess` and add `QSA` flag

Comment: If you add the .htaccess in the subdirectory `my_project`, don't forget to add `RewriteBase /my_project`

Comment: @Dygnus you are saying the following code should work>
`RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /my_project
  RewriteRule ^project/([^/\.]+)/?$ master_page.php?page=$1 [L] [QSA]`

Comment: Yes, it would not break things at least. I've tested your htaccess locally in a subdirectory, works fine. Do you have an .htaccess in a parent directory which is perhaps blocking your requests from going through?